# Want to Simplify C# Access to Dictionary When Key is Tuple

Tags: c#, tuples

Is there a simpler way to check a dictionary where the key is a tuple and then assign the value you were just checking for to a variable?  I've got the following code that works, but it seems tedious.

```
int hitCount = dict.ContainsKey(new Tuple<string, string>(tr, "H"))
   ? dict[new Tuple<string, string>(tr, "H")]
   : 0;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a Tuple as a Key in a Dictionary C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52220354/how-to-use-a-tuple-as-a-key-in-a-dictionary-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Tuple.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387181%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to let the compiler infer generic type parameters from the type of method arguments:

```
int hitCount;
if (!dict.TryGetValue(Tuple.Create(tr, "H"), out hitCount)) {
    hitCount = 0;
}
```

**Note:** Setting `hitCount` to zero is not necessary. This code illustrates how to deal with missing keys, in case you wish to use a different number as a default.

Comment: you really don't need that if and the assignment of  0. That's exactly what `TryGetValue` does

Comment: @adjan I kept the statement structure in place for the case OP wants to use a different default value.

Answer (score 3):

```
int hitCount;
var key = new Tuple<string, string>(tr, "H");
dict.TryGetValue(key, out hitCount);
```

Starting with C# 7:

```
var key = new Tuple<string, string>(tr, "H");
dict.TryGetValue(key, out int hitCount);
```

The difference is that the declaration of `hitCount` is moved to the place where it's used as an `out` parameter.

It's obviously not really necessary to define the key in a separate variable, but in these scenarios you're likely going to want to add the key if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Dictionary<K,V>.TryGetValue`:

```
int hitCount;
dict.TryGetValue(new Tuple<string, string>(tr, "H"), out hitCount);
```

If the value is not found, `hitCount` will be assigned to `int`'s default value, that is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

In the off-chance this might help others, with C# 7.0 you can declare and even name the fields in your tuple, and easily retrieve those values for logging or other manipulation.

```
var tupleKey = (FirstParam: tr, SecondParam: "H");

if (dict.ContainsKey(tupleKey))
{
     _logger.Log($"Found key using {tupleKey.FirstParam} and {tupleKey.SecondParam}.");
     return dict[tupleKey];
}
return 0;
```

Or for quick recall:

```
dict.TryGetValue(tupleKey, out int hitCount);
```