# How to use a Tuple as a Key in a Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, tuples

I have a Dictionary `fieldTracker` which takes a `Tuple<int, int>` as Key and `string` as value. However, I can't seem to find the right way to access the value. Here is my current code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
      dict.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(i, j), "");
  }
  dict[(1,1)] = "Hello";
```

I've searched around a bit in the Microsoft documentation, but can't find the *key* to this problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
dict[Tuple.Create(1, 1)] = "Hello";
```

or with C#7 [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<(int, int), string>();
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        dict.Add((i, j), "");
}
dict[(1, 1)] = "Hello";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way.

```
        var dict = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                dict.Add(Tuple.Create<int, int>(i, j), "Hello");
        }
        string val = dict[Tuple.Create<int, int>(1,1)];
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm not sure why this one didn't have an upvote before posting.  While I'm all on board the ValueTuple usage, it is extremely useful to have both of these side by side.